# Numpy interpolation on pandas TimeStamp data works if it's a pandas series but not if it's a single object?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, interpolation

I'm trying to use `np.interp` to interpolate a float value based on pandas TimeStamp data. However, I noticed that `np.interp` works if the input `x` is a pandas TimeStamp pandas series, but not if it's a single `TimeStamp` object.

Here's the code to illustrate this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
coarse = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2016-01-01 07:00:00.00000+00:00', 
                                      '2016-01-01 07:30:00.00000+00:00',]} )
fine = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2016-01-01 07:00:02.156657+00:00', 
                                      '2016-01-01 07:00:15+00:00', 
                                      '2016-01-01 07:00:32+00:00',
                                      '2016-01-01 07:11:17+00:00',
                                      '2016-01-01 07:14:00+00:00',
                                      '2016-01-01 07:15:55+00:00',
                                      '2016-01-01 07:33:04+00:00'],
                        'price':     [0,
                                      1,
                                      2,
                                      3,
                                      4,
                                      5,
                                      6,
                        ]} )
coarse['start'] = pd.to_datetime(coarse['start'])
fine['start'] = pd.to_datetime(fine['start'])
np.interp(x=coarse.start, xp=fine.start, fp=fine.price) # works
np.interp(x=coarse.start.iloc[-1], xp=fine.start, fp=fine.price)  # doesn't work
```

The latter gives the error

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

I am wondering why the latter doesn't work, while the former does?

Comment: Did you examine `coarse.start.iloc[-1]` by itself?

Answer (score 1):

The input of [`interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) must be an "array-like" (iterable), you can use `.iloc[[-1]]`:

```
np.interp(x=coarse.start.iloc[[-1]], xp=fine.start, fp=fine.price)
```

Output: `array([5.82118562])`

Comment: Oh I see, so the error output is a bit misleading in this case? It doesn't mean anything about it being "array-like"/iterability

Comment: It's maybe a bit more complex. If you pass an integer it accepts it… I cannot tell you the exact reason in terms of library design ;)

Comment: Be also aware that the x values must be increasing, but that failing to do so would still provide incorrect results without error. It's always a good idea to read the docs ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you get when selecting an item from the Series:

```
In [8]: coarse.start
Out[8]: 
0   2016-01-01 07:00:00+00:00
1   2016-01-01 07:30:00+00:00
Name: start, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

In [9]: coarse.start.iloc[-1]
Out[9]: Timestamp('2016-01-01 07:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

With the list index, it's a Series:

```
In [10]: coarse.start.iloc[[-1]]
Out[10]: 
1   2016-01-01 07:30:00+00:00
Name: start, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

I was going to scold you for not showing the full error message, but I see that it's a compiled piece of code that raises the error.  Keep in mind that `interp` is a numpy function, which works with numpy arrays, and for math like this, float dtype ones.

So it's a good guess that `interp` is trying to make a float array from your argument.

```
In [14]: np.asarray(coarse.start, dtype=float)
Out[14]: array([1.4516316e+18, 1.4516334e+18])

In [15]: np.asarray(coarse.start.iloc[[1]], dtype=float)
Out[15]: array([1.4516334e+18])

In [16]: np.asarray(coarse.start.iloc[1], dtype=float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 1
----> 1 np.asarray(coarse.start.iloc[1], dtype=float)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

It can't make a float value from a Python `TimeStamp` object.